# Where I can find S&P 500 stock data history?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, historical-data, online-data-source

I want the history in excel format. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're after a price time series and not a list of S&P 500 constituents?

Yahoo Finance is always a reasonable starting point.

Code you're after is ^GSPC: [https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?p=^GSPC](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?p=%5EGSPC)

There's a download data button on the right side.